# jQuery draggable revert : function() can't return "invalid"

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

So I want a piece of code executed when a draggable is reverted because it wasn't dropped on a droppable. Unfortunately return "invalid"; doens't seem to work, revert is acting like revert:true;
Any suggestions how I can solve this?

```
revert: function () {
            //do some extra stuff...
            return 'invalid';
            }
```

Comment: revert is not a event, its a parameter that should be set to "valid"/"invalid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hemant is right insofar that `revert`is not an event, it is an option, but its accepted values are not valid/invalid but **true/false**.

See the [jquery-ui-draggable manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable) which states:

> If set to true, the element will return to its start position when
>   dragging stops. Possible string values: 'valid', 'invalid'. If set to
>   invalid, revert will only occur if the draggable has not been dropped
>   on a droppable. For valid, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but I figured out a simple answer.

In order to both run a function and apply the "valid/invalid" options of a revert in a draggable, do the following 2 steps:

1) Set the revert option on your draggable object to whichever option you want, like so:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ revert: "valid" /*or invalid*/ });
```

2) Create a function on the droppable's accept option, using the draggable as parameter, and return true, like so:

```
$("droppable").droppable({ 
    accept: function(drag) {
    //insert your code here
    //you can modify the draggable's properties by using $(drag)
    return true;
    }
});
```

Tested on JQuery 3.3.1.

Note: this ALWAYS runs the function, while keeping the "valid/invalid" functionality. To run the function only on a specific case, my guess is that you would have to modify the return value of the accept function.